# gtk+ Image draw over image in c++

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I would like to draw a simple (red) line **over** an image with gtkmm (in c++).

I have the image : `Gtk::Image *image` which is displayed in my window.

But I would like the line to change of position (I mean : draw another line) when a function is called. I need your help because I didn't find how to draw **over** an existing image...

Thank you for your help !

EDIT : A solution for me would be to overlay the image by an image with alpha channel... but I don't know how to to that :-/

Answer (score 1):

You should not actually draw *in* the image, instead you draw in the window.

First put the image in the window (blitting or some other means) then draw the line.

See e.g. [this link](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.4/sec-cairo-drawing-lines.html.en) on how to draw straight lines.

Comment: I don't know how to "blit" with gtk ...
Sorry but it is the first time I use gtk and I am a little bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the "expose-event" (GTK2) or "draw" (GTK3) signal of the GtkImage. I think you should use the C++ equivalent of `g_signal_connect_after` (which in in GObject), and not the `g_signal_connect` one, so you get a chance of drawing after the image has been drawn, so your drawing is on top of it. To draw you need to use cairomm, and Joachim already gave you a link to a [cairomm tutorial](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.4/sec-cairo-drawing-lines.html.en).

Comment: I almost have a working example of this answer, except that mine is written in Python. Shouldn't this answer be accepted?